# Scatterplot matrixes with boxplots for categorical data

Tags: r, statistics

I'm a big fan of [SPLOMs](http://schamberlain.github.com/2011/03/for-all-your-pairwise-comparison-needs/)

Does anyone know of SPLOM packages that can support boxplots for categorical data? It looks really weird when you have scatterplots for columns like "gender"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, this would make helping much easier.

Comment: I think Zeke's idea can be reproduced with `data(iris); library(lattice);splom(iris)`

Comment: The `gpairs` function in the `YaleToolkit` package used to be able to do this, at least a bunch of years ago. Ah, now it's its own package: the `gpairs` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `GGally` package, it support a lot of feature.

```
require(GGally)
data(tips)
tips.sample <- tips[ ,c("total_bill", "tip", "day")]

ggpairs(tips.sample, upper = list(continuous = "points", combo = "box"), 
                     lower = list(continuous = "points", combo = "box"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get histograms on the diagonal labels? I find that exceptionally helpful with this kind of matrix.

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg  Try this `gpairs(tips.sample, upper = list(continuous = "points", combo = "box"), 
                     lower = list(continuous = "points", combo = "facethist"))`